# SEO friendly url using php

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, seo

I am trying to make SEO friendly website using php...

In folder jcheck i have a index.php file which take one parameter "id" as input.

```
mydomain.com/jcheck/index.php?id=1 works
```

How can i make it as follow

```
mydomain.com/jcheck/1
```

I have tried making .htaccess file and putting

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} 1/
RewriteRule 1/ http://mydomain.com/jcheck/index.php?id=1
```

How can i make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can essentially do this 2 ways:**

**The .htaccess route with mod_rewrite**

Add a file called .htaccess in your root folder, and add something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/Some-text-goes-here/([0-9]+)$ /picture.php?id=$1
```

This will tell Apache to enable mod_rewrite for this folder, and if it gets asked a URL matching the regular expression it rewrites it internally to what you want, without the end user seeing it. Easy, but inflexible, so if you need more power:

The PHP route

**Put the following in your .htaccess instead:**

```
FallbackResource index.php
```

This will tell it to run your index.php for all files it cannot normally find in your site. In there you can then for example:

```
$path = ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');    // Trim leading slash(es)
$elements = explode('/', $path);                // Split path on slashes
if(count($elements) == 0)                       // No path elements means home
    ShowHomepage();
else switch(array_shift($elements))             // Pop off first item and switch
{
    case 'Some-text-goes-here':
        ShowPicture($elements); // passes rest of parameters to internal function
        break;
    case 'more':
        ...
    default:
        header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
        Show404Error();
}
```

This is how big sites and CMS-systems do it, because it allows far more flexibility in parsing URLs, config and database dependent URLs etc. For sporadic usage the hardcoded rewrite rules in .htaccess will do fine though.

*****Copy this content from [URL rewriting with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)**

Comment: This is a cool solution the second one, but isn't it slower than the first one?

Comment: For me, `count($elements)` contains an empty string for root calls (home). It can be caught with a case for empty string (i.e. `case '':`). Also, `FallbackResource index.php` was failing on root. Instead I got it working with the traditional mod_rewrite from [link](https://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2012/01/21/apaches-fallbackresource-your-new-htaccess-command/).

Comment: i have many url for same as above. so create one by one  define in  .htaccess route with mod_rewrite. if you posible one time define. please quik answer

Answer (score 2):

In the htaccess file in your jcheck directory, use these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /jcheck/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: The requested URL /jcheck/3 was not found on this server.

Comment: @user1853803 are you sure your htaccess file is being processed? Those rules work fine for me in a blank htaccess file

Comment: is there any permission or something which needs to be set

Comment: @user1853803 you need `AllowOverride FileInfo` or `AllowOveride All` in your vhost/server config

Comment: how can i check if .htaccess file is processed

Comment: @user1853803 add some gibberish to it, if you don't get an error when you visit `/jcheck/index.php`, it's being ignored

Comment: how can i do this...plz help i am doing this for first time

Comment: gibberish where? can i start chat

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37448/discussion-between-user1853803-and-jon-lin)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
RewriteRule ^jcheck/([0-9]+)$ jcheck/index.php?id=$1
```

Comment: What you get when enter url?

Comment: Not Found

The requested URL /jcheck/3/ was not found on this server.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/jcheck/([0-9]+)$ /jcheck/index.php?id=1
```

and see also **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)** it will usefull for you

Comment: http://mydomain.com/jcheck/1/ gives me The requested URL /jcheck/1/ was not found on this server.

Answer (score 0):

Put .htaccess file inside `jcheck` folder and write:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-D
RewriteRule ^1/?$ index.php?id=1
```

Comment: its not working give me 404 not found error

Comment: @user1853803 did u put the .htaccess file inside jcheck?

Comment: yes i have put the .htaccess inside jcheck

Comment: can you share your real URL? I guess that its caching issue now